# Combining CSV files into one dataframe in Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a folder with many .csv files. Each .csv is basically a serie with each row including a timestamp in seconds and the value of that observation. So a row could look like: `7.845442177,355.333`. The number of rows in each file is not necessarily the same. Further, there are no headers but the .csv file has a unique name. I would like to create a dataframe to work with that looks like this:

```
filename_1        filename_2        ...   filename_n
<numeric value>   <numeric value>   ...   <numeric value>   
   .                 .               .       .  
   .                 .               .       .
   .                 .               .       .
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I am new to python so every little tip is much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you discarding the timestamps in the final dataframe?

Comment: Yes, but if there's an easy way to 'save them' for (potentially) later use, that would be great as well.